# java code is showing error. ( ';',expected)

Tags: java

```
class B {
  int x,y;
  int z;
  z=x*y;

  void show() {
    System.out.println(z);
  }
}

class A {
  public static void main(String as[]) {
    B b=new B();
    b.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code correctly and print the full error message (including line number)?

Comment: if you somehow make it correct (constructor or initializer block), you should heavily think of the logic behind it, because, you have x and y uninitialized.

Comment: @Sarwar, strictly speaking, x and y are initialized to the default value of zero. Thankfully, there is no such thing as uninitialized variables in Java. Of course, it still makes little sense to multiply two zeroes and store the result in another field.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov: little sense or no sense?

Comment: @Sarwar, you got me there. It makes some sense if the guy is just learning the language syntax, which is apparently is what he's doing. But of course it makes no sense in a real life program.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't have statements in the class body (`z=x*y;`). You have (at least) two options:

- `int z = x * y;`
- use initializer block

  ```
  {
    z = x * y;
  }
  ```

These are virtually the same. I'd prefer the first option (cleaner) [See here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: Or a constructor, or even a field initializer (`int z = x * y`).

Comment: I showed the field initializer. The constructor is also an option, but not preferred if many constructors are likely to exist.

Comment: well, these are virtually the same :) I'd prefer the first option

Comment: I'd disagree and go with the constructor. The field initializer is practically equally as valid, but since the question here is almost definitely from a beginners perspective it's constructors he should be learning about for this sort of thing, or at least he should be learning about them before initialization blocks!

Comment: @Bozho, well, it is arguable. Many constructors can call each other to avoid duplicating code (but you have to remember to do it), while initializer blocks can have troubles with exception handling. Of course, in this case there are no exceptions so using an initializer is no problem I think.

Answer (score 3):

`z=x*y;` you cant do it here. put it inside constructor

```
class B {
  int x,y;
  int z;
  //z=x*y; //you cant do it here. where are you getting x and y value by the way???

  public B()
  {
   //x and y values should be set 'somehow' before this
   z = x*y;
  }

  void show() {
    System.out.println(z);
  }
}
```

Comment: use Bozho's solution... initializer block...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in these lines:

```
int z;
z=x*y;
```

This first line is perfectly fine - it declares a class instance variable called `z` of type `int`.  This second line, however, is the source of your problem.  In Java, it's illegal to have code in a class outside of a class method or static initializer.  In this case, the statement `z = x * y;` is legal Java code, but it has to be inside of a method.

To fix this, you can move this code into a constructor or some other method.

Answer (score 0):

```
  z=x*y;
```

mentioned not within method body. You can't do that. Move it to the constructor or another method.

Inside class body and outside method body you can mention only fields, methods and inner class declarations.