# Application class can't change subclass fields

Tags: java, inheritance, field

I'm having a problem with my Java assignment on inheritance.  I won't go into detail on the task as that's not my issue.  In the program. have a superclass with some fields in it.  Two of these fields are ints, xCoord and yCoord.  There is then a subclass that obviously also has these ints.  It also has another attribute, short direction, that is not contained in the superclass.  I need to access all three of these attributes in the user class.  The user class needs to be able to change these values.  When attempting to compile.  I get the error:

```
error:  ';' expected
```

in all the lines in my user class that try to increment xCoord or yCoord.  For example:

```
mov1.yCoord++
    ^
```

So, I don't really know what the problem is.  I assume it has something to do with the attributes not be directly declared in that class.  My reasoning for this is because I have lines that deal with the short direction in the same manner.  For example:

```
mov1.direction = 1
```

This goes through the compiler with no problem.  So I reckon in must be because xCoord and yCoord only declared in the super class.  But that's just my assumption, I could be wrong.  Regardless if whether I am or not, I need to fix this while still using inheritance for these fields, the assignment requires it.  Any help?

For reference, here are some snippets of relevant code:

The superclass:  (didn't include the methods because not relevant)

```
public class StationaryThing    {

// Attributes

protected String name;
protected final int gridlength = 10;
protected final int gridwidth = 10;
public int xCoord;
public int yCoord;

// Constructor

public StationaryThing(String name, int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    this.name = name;
    this.xCoord = xCoord;
    this.yCoord = yCoord;
}
```

The subclass:  (again, didn't include methods)

```
public class MovingThing extends StationaryThing    {

// Attributes

public short direction = 0;

// Constructor

public MovingThing(String name, int xCoord, int yCoord) {
    super(name, xCoord, yCoord);
}
```

And some of the relevant lines from the user class:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noMoves; i++)   {
    if (mov1.direction == 0)    {
        if (hole1.xCoord == mov1.xCoord && hole1.yCoord == mov1.yCoord+1)   {
            mov1.direction = 1;
            mov1.holeAhead();
            mov1.directionChange();
            }

        if (mov1.yCoord == 9)   {
            mov1.direction = 1;
            mov1.directionchange();
            }

        else    {
            mov1.displayAttributes
            mov1.yCoord++;
            }
        }
```

Again, thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of  `mov1.displayAttributes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those lines "missing ;" inside a method? There cannot be "just code" inside the class, but there should be a method like

```
public void doSth () {
    a++;
}
```

Please refer [java code is showing error. ( ';',expected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861149/java-code-is-showing-error-expected) for a similar situation.

Comment: Also do check every statement has a ; at the end, like @Sotirios said. Your code examples did not have it always in place. Do you e.g. really have a line mov1.yCoord++ without ; at end? Well, adding it may help on that.